ImageMagick command to rescale only the shorter axis and keep aspect ratio
I have seen the use of the > operator for the geometry of the -rescale option for ImageMagick, which basically ensures that the longer axis is scaled down to the desired length. What I am looking for is similar, but for the shorter axis. Also, > apparently prevents any upscaling, which is not what I want.
Let me explain with an example:

The desired size of an image is given as X, let's say 512 pixels.
An image with resolution 1920x1080 would be scaled down to (roughly) 910x512, because y is the shorter axis, therefore it gets rescaled to 512, and x scales down accordingly, preserving aspect ratio
An image with resolution 1000x3000 would be scaled down to 512x1536, because x is the shorter axis, therefore it gets rescaled to 512, and y scales down accordingly, preserving aspect ratio
An image with resolution 600x300 would be scaled up to 1024x512, because y is the shorter axis, therefore it gets rescaled to 512, and x scales up accordingly, preserving aspect ratio

Is there an existing command or syntax in ImageMagick that I can use to accomplish this?

The shorter axis rescale is done with the ^. If on windows you need to escape that symbol with ^, so ^^. Please see https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

This ImageMagick v7 command will take any input image and resize it so the shorter of width or height will be 512 pixels, while maintaining the aspect of the original...
magick input.png -resize "%[fx:w<h?512:w/512*w]x%[fx:h<w?512:h/512*h]!" output.png

It uses conditional FX expressions to check the shorter of width or height, then calculates the length required for the other leg, and resizes the image to those dimensions. Obviously not every dimension will be evenly divisible to exactly match the input aspect ratio, and I'm not sure how IM might handle that, like rounding up or down, if it's a fractional result. It seems any "error" could only be one pixel more or less.
